# Identity Server 4 User management API

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi

I've managed to get a solution working with a single page application project (`ReactJS`), an API running on `ASP.net Core` project and an `IdentityServer 4` project.

I want to be able to call an API on the `IdentityServer 4` project from the single page application project.

I created a simple controller class in the `IdentityServer 4` application, with the authorize attribute. If I call it via `Postman`, however, I get the HTML for the login page back.

This happens after I already logged in on the API, and I use that same token.

How am I supposed to log in to identity server to make calls to it to manage users?

Comment: You should show the relevant code. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you should definitely add more information to your question. Your controller is part of the identity server's mvc application? Are you using AspnetCore.Identity?

If so, your controller is protected by AspnetCore.Identities's cookie authentication scheme. You need to send the cookie to access the controller. This has nothing to do with identity server as you are on the local MVC application, it's just plain vanilla MVC.

Postman has problems sending cookies, you need the [interceptor chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo). You also need to login though postman.

This will probably work if the SPA is hosted by the same MVC application. If not you will need to configure your mvc applications to validate access tokens (not just issue them), like this:

```
// Adds IdentityServer
app.UseIdentityServer();

// Accept access tokens from identity server
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
    RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
    AuthenticationScheme = "Bearer"

    ApiName = "api1"
});
```

This way you can request access tokens for your local api through identity server, (You also need to configure an api scope for 'api1').

To validate them in your api-controller add this to your controller:

```
    [Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string Bearer()
    {
        return "Access Token Accepted";
    }
```